# Show item that does not belong to the user

Tags: laravel, eloquent, load

I have items and users who have a many to many relationship. 
I want to show the user all items that are not his own, how can I show that?

EDIT:

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'interest_user');
}

public function interests()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interest', 'interest_user');
}
```

EDIT2:
I changed the code but I get the same error message

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
public function interests()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Interest::class);
}

Schema::create('interest_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('interest_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('interest_id')->references('id')->on('interests')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });


$suggestinterests = Interest::whereHas('user_id', function ($q) use ($user) {
    $q->where('user_id', '!=', $user);
    })->get();
```

Errormessage:Call to undefined method App\Interest::whereHas()

EDIT3:
this code works!

```
$suggestinterests =  \App\Interest::whereHas('user', function ($q){
        $q->where('user_id', '!=', auth()->id());
    })->get();
```

Comment: your relationship is wrong! look at my answer....

Comment: what's the difference between pivot table (interest_user) and Item::class/User::class?

Comment: The migration file is different... never ever use some custom names. Always use Model::class in relationships because laravel is made like that. And in your migration files for foreign keys give the name like: 'model_id'

Comment: I changed it, but I get the same error

Answer (score 2):

```
class User
{
    public function items()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
    }
}

class Item
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}


Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('item_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Retrieve Records:

```
$availableItems = Item::whereHas('user_id', function ($q) use (Auth::user()->id {
    $q->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```

This is written very raw, you will probably need to adapt it!

Comment: i get the error message: ´ SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `items` where `user_id` != 1) ´

Comment: @slickness you need to provide us with attributes of both your models, User and Item

Comment: My tables look like this too. I'm getting this error message: parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'auth' (T_STRING), expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: I have adapted and changed the code. Now I get a new error: `Call to undefined method App \ Interest :: whereHas ()`      `$user = Auth::user()->id;
        $suggestinterests = Interest::whereHas('user_id', function ($q) use ($user) {
        $q->where('user_id', '!=', $user);
        })->get();`

Comment: Sorry but you will have to add your model relationships code and migrations file and the controller where you call that function to get the wanted data. It is very hard to say where you have made the mistake without the code.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure it out

```
 $all_items_but_excluded_user_items = DB::table('interests')
         ->select('name',DB::raw('interest_user.interest_id as pivot_interest_id'),
         DB::raw('interest_user.user_id as pivot_user_id'))
         ->join('interest_user','interests.id','=','interest_user.item_id')
         ->where('interest_user.user_id','!=',$user->id)
         ->get();
```